# Showing shareable URLs in the address bar of Dynamics CRM?

Tags: browser, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I would like to enable shareable URLs (shown as *https://crm.myorg.com/main.aspx?etc=X&extraqs=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&pagetype=XXXXXXX*) to be displayed directly in the address bar, instead of having to click "Email a link" and retrieving the URL from there. Right now each page shows the URLs as *https://crm.myorg.com/main.aspx#XXXXXXXX*

Is there a way to do it? I am using MS CRM Dynamics 2013 On-Premise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this with a JS hack.

1. Add the code below to a JS Web Resource
2. Set the OnLoad method of a chosen entity to call the `SetAddressBarAsFormShortcut()` function

Note that unfortunately it's impossible to enable this behavior globally (unless Microsoft's JS files are modified) and it only works for browsers supporting the history.pushState() method.

```js
function UpdateAddressBar(entityTitle, recordId, entityLogicalName) {
    var $v_0 = Mscrm.CrmUri.create(window.location.href);
    if (Mscrm.SessionInfo.isOutlookLaptopClient() && !Mscrm.SessionInfo.isOnline()) {
        var $v_2 = window.location.href, $v_3 = window.location.pathname;
        $v_0 = Mscrm.CrmUri.create(Mscrm.Help.concatenateUrl(window.WEB_APP_URL, $v_2.substr($v_2.indexOf($v_3))));
        $v_0.set_useOrganizationName(false)
    }
    if (!Mscrm.Utilities.isNewPageModel($v_0)) {
        $v_0 = Mscrm.Utilities.removeExtraQSParameters($v_0, Mscrm.Utilities.getRecordPageQueryStringParams());
        if (Mscrm.InternalUtilities.EntityNames.Calendar === entityLogicalName && (IsNull($v_0.get_query()["id"]) || isNullOrEmptyString($v_0.get_query()["id"])) && !IsNull(recordId)) {
            $v_0.get_query()["calendarId"] = recordId;
            $v_0.get_query()["calendarType"] = 1;
            $v_0 = Mscrm.Utilities.removeExtraQSParameters($v_0, ["calendarId", "calendarType"])
        }
    } else {
        $v_0 = Mscrm.Utilities.getPageUrl($v_0, "entityrecord");
        delete $v_0.get_query().pagemode;
        if (!IsNull(recordId))
            $v_0.get_query()["id"] = recordId;
        delete $v_0.get_query().extraqs;
        var $v_4 = $find("crmFormSelector");
        if ($v_4)
            $v_0.get_query()["extraqs"] = "formid=" + CrmEncodeDecode.CrmUrlEncode($v_4.$r_3)
    }
    $v_0 = $v_0.toString();
    $v_0 = $v_0.substring($v_0.indexOf("main.aspx"));
    top.onpopstate = function(){top.history.pushState("", "", "main.aspx"); top.onpopstate = null; top.history.go(-2)};
    top.history.pushState("", "", $v_0);     
};

function SetAddressBarAsFormShortcut() {
    var $v_0 = Xrm.Page.data.entity;
    UpdateAddressBar(CrmEncodeDecode.CrmHtmlDecode($v_0.getPrimaryAttributeValue()), $v_0.getId(), $v_0.getEntityName())
}
```

(The code above is based on the code Microsoft uses in the `Email a link`/`Copy a link` function)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have shareable URLs with CRM 2013 in the address bar.

You need to get the link by `E-mail a Link` or `Copy a Link` functions.

Comment: I've found a way to do it with JS, see my answer :)